# Maximize returns an incorrect answer with a linear function and equality constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I tried to optimize a linear function with equality constraints using Maximize and I noticed that it returns an infeasible solution without any warnings.

The problem is this:

[image: The problem statement]

Which I formulated in Mathematica like so:

```
Maximize[{x1 + x2, x1 + x2 == 7, x1 + 4*x2 == 16, 3*x1 + 2*x2 == 18, x1 >= 0, x2 
>= 0}, {x1, x2}]
```

> {16, {x1 -> 16, x2 -> 0}}

Mathematica does not warn about the solution not being infeasible, even though it clearly violates the first constraint.
Splitting the first constraint into two $\ge$ and $\le$ constraints gives the correct answer:

```
Maximize[{x1 + x2, x1 + x2 <= 7, x1 + x2 >= 7, x1 + 4*x2 == 16, 3*x1 + 2*x2 == 18, x1 
>= 0, x2 >= 0}, {x1, x2}]
```

> {7, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 3}}

What's the problem here?
I'm using Mathematica 12.0.0 built on April 9, 2019.

Comment: You can find the answer by realizing that the first two constraints uniquely specify x1 and x2: Solve[{x1 + x2 == 7, x1 + 4*x2 == 16}, {x1, x2}] returns the answer.

Comment: Of course I can, but that does not answer my question. Why doesn't Maximize work correctly?

Comment: You can make sure your constraints are sensible: Reduce[{x1 + x2 == 7, x1 + 4*x2 == 16, 3*x1 + 2*x2 == 18, x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0}, {x1, x2}]. Right away you would see that the maximization problem is not meaningful.

Comment: That Reduce returns "x1 == 4 && x2 == 3" which seems to be an entirely reasonable thing to maximize x1+x2 with? Maximize returns x1=16,x2=0 not x1=4,x2=3

Comment: Reduce is telling you that there is only one possible x1 and x2 that fulfill the constraint(s). There is nothing to maximize!

Comment: Clearly I can see that, but why what is the reason Maximize doesn't? Why does it return an incorrect answer for a simple linear problem with equality constraints?

Comment: I would suggest deleting this question as it is a simple deliberate mistake on the part of the user.

Comment: @rmw I disagree about deleting the question as this is confusing behaviour. Why do the conditions {x1>0, x2>0} result in the right answer but the more relaxed constrains allowing for equality {x1>=0, x2>=0} do not?  Moreover, why does the version by user64494 in the comments of your response result in yet another answer? Being a linear problem it should not be hard for Mathematica to optimize it.